# How to use libclang with STL?

Tags: c++, windows, stl, mingw, libclang

I'm trying to parse a library using libclang, and I'm stuck with what could be a very simple issue: how to configure it with STL?
At the moment, it fails to parse a translation unit because it can't find `<string>`.

Here's what I tried :

```
char *args[] = {"-x", "c++", "-Ic:/my/library/includes", "-IG:/Prog/libcxx-3.4/include"};
clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, "c:/my/library/test.cpp", args, 4, 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm on windows, with the precompiled clang binaries downloaded from llvm.org, and I tried with various STL implementations :

- Visual studio
- MingW
- libCXX

In each case, I ended up with unknown types.

For example, with mingw, I've got the following error messages :

```
/mingw/include\wchar.h:221:71: error: unknown type name '_locale_t'
/mingw/include\wchar.h:223:81: error: unknown type name '_locale_t'
/mingw/include\stdlib.h:173:65: error: unknown type name '_locale_t'
/mingw/include\stdlib.h:175:75: error: unknown type name '_locale_t'
/mingw/include\io.h:301:14: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
/mingw/include\io.h:301:36: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
/mingw/include\io.h:302:14: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
/mingw/include\io.h:302:39: error: unknown type name 'off64_t'
/mingw/include\unistd.h:65:20: error: unknown type name 'off_t'
```

The rare tutorials I've found about this subject don't talk about this subject...

Comment: Can I ask how you managed to include and link libclang?

Answer (score 2):

Since libclang was precompiled, it doesn't know about the exact paths of the standard libraries used by your compilers. You'll have to tell it about the standard include path using `-I` switches in your arguments list, when calling `clang_parseTranslationUnit`.

Here is the command I use to find about the inclusion paths for `gcc` on Linux. You should be able to adapt it to MinGW in your windows environment:

```sh
$ echo "" | g++ -v -x c++ -E -
```

```
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
...
```