# Python clang does not search system include paths

Tags: python, c++, clang, libclang

When using libclang from Python, it doesn't seem to automatically search the system's include paths.

Is there a reliable way to get these paths? I don't like hardcoding paths as I'm writing code that will run on a variety of UNIX systems.

For example, given test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

and test.py

```
from clang.cindex import Index

tu = Index.create().parse(None, ["test.cpp"])
print(list(tu.diagnostics))
```

running `python test.py` will print:

```
[<Diagnostic severity 4, location <SourceLocation file 'test.cpp', line 1, 
 column 10>, spelling "'stdio.h' file not found">]
```

Of course, I can find the system include paths by doing

```
$ clang -v -E test.cpp
```

and adding `"-Isome/path"` to the `parse` argument-list, i.e.

```
args = ["-I/Applications/[...]", "test.cpp"]
```

That actually works and produces no errors.

However, this isn't portable, and it would be really nice if I could programmatically get clang to automatically use them.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22536040/528929) answers there's no better way only with libclang(seems that libtooling is more capable); a workaround is adding a call to `clang -E -x c++ /dev/null -v` and filter the result within python script.

Comment: consider using `-isystem<path>` instead of `-I<path>` to inform libclang of the system include paths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This question has been up for some time, so I'll attempt to answer it myself.*

It seems that even Clang itself uses mostly hardcoded paths.

It enumerates candidate paths and adds the ones that fit under the current context. This can be seen in [clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp#L330-L414). E.g.,

```
AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
                           "i686-apple-darwin10", "", "x86_64", triple);
AddGnuCPlusPlusIncludePaths("/usr/include/c++/4.0.0",
                           "i686-apple-darwin8", "", "", triple);

// ...
```

For Linux, this code has the notice:

```
llvm_unreachable("Include management is handled in the driver.");
```

Under `clang/lib/Driver/` we can find more of these paths in files such as `ToolChains.cpp`, `CrossWindowsToolChain.cpp` and `MinGWToolChain.cpp`.

What I was hoping for was that the code in `InitHeaderSearch.cpp` would be exposed to Python through libclang.