# libclang: add compiler system include path (Python in Windows)

Tags: python, c++, clang, libclang

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098725/parsing-with-libclang-unable-to-parse-certain-tokens-python-in-windows) and [Andrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100397/6167676) suggestions, I am trying to have **liblang** **add the compiler system include paths** (in Windows) in order for my Python code

```
import clang.cindex

def parse_decl(node):
    reference_node = node.get_definition()
    if node.kind.is_declaration():
        print(node.kind, node.kind.name, 
              node.location.line, ',', node.location.column, 
              reference_node.displayname)

    for ch in node.get_children():
        parse_decl(ch)

# configure path
clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/libclang.dll')

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
trans_unit = index.parse(r'C:\path\to\sourcefile\test.cpp', args=['-std=c++11'])

parse_decl(trans_unit.cursor)
```

to *completely* **parse C++ source files** like this one

```
/* test.cpp
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void readfunction(vector<double>& numbers, ifstream& myfile)
{

  double number;
  while (myfile >> number) {
  numbers.push_back(number);}

}

double meanfunction(vector<double>& numbers)
{

  double total=0;
  vector<double>::const_iterator i;
  for (i=numbers.begin(); i!=numbers.end(); ++i) {
  total +=*i; }
  return total/numbers.size();

}
```

Now, without the compiler system include path set up appropriately (using Windows), I get the following output:

```
CursorKind.USING_DIRECTIVE USING_DIRECTIVE 8 , 17 std
CursorKind.VAR_DECL VAR_DECL 10 , 6 readfunction

Process finished with exit code 0

<Diagnostic severity 4, location <SourceLocation file 'test.cpp', line 3, column 10>, spelling "'iostream' file not found">
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make sense (new in Python and Clang) of this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946295/6167676) or how to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440911/python-clang-does-not-search-system-include-paths) in my Python code.

I have also tried [ccsyspath](https://github.com/AndrewWalker/ccsyspath), but I do not have the skills to 'adjust it for windows'.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows to add something to the path you must do the following:

1. System properties
2. Advanced
3. Environment variables
4. Select "path" from the table
5. First "edit" button
6. Add in the location of the executable that you are trying to add to path

Hope this helps!

---

(Please tell me if I misunderstood your question, I am still new to stack overflow. Thanks!)